# Remix App - inconsistent behavior between dev and production?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm-start, remix.run

I noticed that on Remix, the behaviour is different between running the dev server with `npm run dev` vs `npm run build && npm start`

When using the indi template, but also the jokes app example, login and logout don't work anymore once not running in the dev server.

I tried with fresh projects of both, I also tried with a fresh project initiated without a template and copied over the ./app and ./prisma directories from the indi stack template and it exhibited the same behaviour, for instance when logging in, it just redirects to the sign in page. When logging in on the dev server and then running build and start, I can't log out.

As typescript/javascript aren't my primary language, I am unsure how to narrow this down, but I can consistently reproduce this problem without changing any code in the template at all.

In the server logs there are no errors thrown.

I am wondering now, is this something I am doing wrong or is this an issue with Remix itself?

**Expected behaviour:** Logout, Login etc work as expected in production, just like they do when running `npm run dev`

**Observed behaviour:** Logout doesn't work when using a valid session, login redirects to the login page without actually logging the user in. This is consistent when running a remix app with `npm run build && npm start`

I also tried with yarn and pnpm to make sure it is not an npm bug, but the problem is still reproducible

Comment: I figured it out. Once I added a reverse proxy with https enabled, it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
Once I added a reverse proxy with valid tls certificate it runs like it should.

Comment: Could you expand this answer? maybe link something about the topic or explain why you need it? I'm facing the same issue